# ManageIQ web application inside Docker container can’t connect to Hawkular outside container

Tags: ssl, docker, manageiq

I use monitoring application "ManageIQ" inside Docker container with the ssl port to check the application "hawkular" which is located outside the Docker container. Below are the docker commands:

```
docker pull manageiq/manageiq:euwe-2
docker run --privileged -d -p 8443:443 manageiq/manageiq:euwe-2
```

And I configure the ssl setting inside the "ManageIQ" docker container

```
 docker exec -ti "container-id" bash –l

 [root@17a6a6bd8743 vmdb]# vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
 ServerName localhost:8443
 SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
 SSLCertificateFile /opt/manageiq/manageiq-ui-service/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/manageiq/manageiq-ui-service/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.key
 [root@17a6a6bd8743 vmdb]# systemctl restart httpd 
 [root@17a6a6bd8743 vmdb]# yum install firewalld -y
 [root@17a6a6bd8743 vmdb]# systemctl start firewalld
 [root@17a6a6bd8743 vmdb]# systemctl enable firewalld
[root@17a6a6bd8743 vmdb]# firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent 
 success
[root@17a6a6bd8743 vmdb]# firewall-cmd --reload 
 success
```

The ManageIQ web application https://localhost:8443 works succesfully. But can't connect to hawkular whose URL is http://localhost:8080 located outside the Docker container.

These 2 applications have each different "localhost", however I have no idea how to handle this problem. Do I miss any process to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` in a `container` is not `localhost` on host OS. these are different.

To connect the address of host OS from a `container`, use `docker0` interface which is default `bridge network` docker serves by default. 
(Of course, you could create your own docker network other than default bridge network, refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/))

```
$ ifconfig docker0
```

For example, If `docker0` interface's IP is `172.20.0.1`, Use `172.20.0.1:8080`.